# How can I not use the Facebook for HTC Sense on my HTC Incredible?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-droid-incredible, facebook

I'm trying to add my Facebook account instead of using Facebook for HTC Sense. However, when I go to Accounts & sync > Add account > Facebook, nothing happens. If I tap any other account, I get prompted for login information (or, if I'm already logged in, the ability to change settings or add a second account). I really dislike the Facebook for HTC Sense, so there's got to be a way to add my Facebook account without using Facebook for HTC Sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the actual Facebook for Android app from the Marketplace. This would mean that you use the actual Facebook app rather than Facebook for HTC Sense. Not sure if there is any difference between the two, but I know I have both installed on my Desire and use the actual Facebook for Android app.

Comment: I have the Facebook for Android application made by Facebook and I use it. However, I am unable to sync from it on the Accounts & Sync > Add Account menu.

Comment: For the syncing I use the HTC Facebook app. I just use Facebook for Android to view and comment on Facebook rather than the HTC Facebook app.

Comment: Do you know how to sync using the Facebook for Android instead of the HTC Facebook app, if it is possible? That's really what I want to do.

Comment: It doesn't look like it is possible, The Facebook for Android app displays in Accounts & Sync, but you cannot select it to make use of it. Also tried removing the HTC Facebook App from Sync, but it still doesn't allow Facebook for Android. I guess Facebook will just have to work on a better Android experience as even though it is better than the HTC version, it is still pretty rubbish.